# Is this a modern C++11 implementation of a Level class and static factory?

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11

This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62254/static-factory-function-and-lifetime), now that I've read up more about modern C++ (specifically C++11) and the answers in the question. I'm using MSVC/Visual Studio 2012 Update 4.

Specific things I'm wondering about:

- Am I doing the Exception right? [I asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757875/) regarding an access problem I had, but I also want to know if this is proper style.
- Could there be any portability problems with the `enum class Tile`, specifically with the fact that the values are `char`s that correspond to the text file on disk
- Should the ints that `GetTileAt` and `SetTileAt` take be declared const? Since they are copied by value anyway, that seems superflous?
- Have I done the `Level` ctor right? Based on [glampert](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/39810/glampert)'s suggestion I'm using `std::move` to only construct it at the very end of the `LoadLevelFromFile` method

#### Level.h

```c++
#ifndef WAREHOUSE_LEVEL_H
#define WAREHOUSE_LEVEL_H

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>

enum class Tile : char { 
    Unknown = 0,
    Free = ' ',
    Box = '+',
    Target = '.',
    Wall = '=',
    BoxOnTarget = '*',
    PlayerStart = 'x'
};

class LevelLoadException : public std::exception
{
public:
    LevelLoadException(std::string msg) : m_message(msg) { }
    const char* what () const throw ()
    {
        return m_message.c_str();
    }
private:
    std::string m_message;
};

class Level
{
public:
    const std::string& GetName() const;
    int GetPlayerStartX() const;
    int GetPlayerStartY() const;
    Tile GetTileAt(const int x, const int y) const;
    void SetTileAt(const int x, const int y, Tile tile);
    static std::unique_ptr<Level> LoadFromFile(const std::string& fileName); 

    static const int MaxCols = 30;
    static const int MaxRows = 20;
    static const int TileCount = MaxCols * MaxRows;

    Level(std::vector<Tile>&& tiles, std::string&& mapName, int playerStartX, int playerStartY);
private:
    std::vector<Tile> m_tiles;
    int m_playerStartX, m_playerStartY;
    std::string m_name;
};

#endif
```

#### Level.cpp

```c++
#include "Level.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int GetIndex(int line, int column){
    return (line * Level::MaxCols) + column;
}

const std::string& Level::GetName() const{
    return m_name;
}

int Level::GetPlayerStartX() const{
    return m_playerStartX;
}

int Level::GetPlayerStartY() const{
    return m_playerStartY;
}

Tile Level::GetTileAt(const int x, const int y) const {
    int ix = GetIndex(y, x);
    return m_tiles[ix];
}

void Level::SetTileAt(const int x, const int y, Tile tile){
    int ix = GetIndex(y, x);
    m_tiles[ix] = tile;
}

std::unique_ptr<Level> Level::LoadFromFile(const std::string& fileName){
    std::ifstream file (fileName);    

    int numBoxes = 0;
    int numTargets = 0;
    bool playerStart = false;
    int playerStartX = 0;
    int playerStartY = 0;
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Tile> tiles(TileCount, Tile::Free);

    int y = -1;
    std::string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        if(y == -1){
            name = line;
        }
        else if (y >= Level::MaxRows) {
            throw LevelLoadException(std::string("There are more than ") + std::to_string(Level::MaxRows) + std::string(" rows in the level."));
        }    
        else {
            int lineLength = line.length();

            if(lineLength> Level::MaxCols){
                throw LevelLoadException(std::string("There are more than ") + std::to_string(Level::MaxCols) + std::string(" tiles in a column."));
            }

            for (int x=0; x < lineLength; x++) 
            {
                int ix = GetIndex(y,x);
                char c = line[x];

                switch(c) {
                case Tile::Free:
                    tiles[ix] = Tile::Free;
                    break;
                case Tile::Box:
                    numBoxes++;
                    tiles[ix] = Tile::Box;
                    break;
                case Tile::BoxOnTarget:
                    numBoxes++;
                    numTargets++;
                    tiles[ix] = Tile::BoxOnTarget;
                    break;
                case Tile::Target:
                    numTargets++;
                    tiles[ix] = Tile::Target;
                    break;
                case Tile::Wall:
                    tiles[ix] = Tile::Wall;
                    break;
                case Tile::PlayerStart:
                    if(playerStart) {
                        throw LevelLoadException("There is more than 1 player start in the level.");
                    }
                    playerStart = true;
                    playerStartX = x;
                    playerStartY = y;
                    tiles[ix] = Tile::Free;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw LevelLoadException(std::string("Invalid Character in Level: ") + c);
                }
            }
        }
        y++;
    }

    if(numBoxes != numTargets) 
    {
        throw LevelLoadException(std::string("There are ") + std::to_string(numBoxes) + std::string(" boxes, but ") + std::to_string(numTargets) + std::string(" targets in the level."));
    }

    if(!playerStart){
        throw LevelLoadException("There is no Player Start position in the level.");
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Level> level(new Level(std::move(tiles), std::move(name), playerStartX, playerStartY));
    return level;
}

Level::Level(std::vector<Tile> && tiles, std::string && mapName, int playerStartX, int playerStartY) 
    : m_tiles(tiles), m_name(mapName), m_playerStartX(playerStartX), m_playerStartY(playerStartY) {
}
```

#### level.txt

```
Level Name
   =====
   =   =
   =   =
====   ========
=x   +        =
= +     + + + =
=====     =====
    =.....=
    =======
```

Comment: `Level` has no virtual destructor, so I'm confused as to why you're returning a pointer from the call to `LoadFromFile`. Is `Level` meant to be a base class of a class heirarchy?

Comment: Agreed with Yuushi; it's not clear from the visible code why `LoadFromFile` doesn't return a `Level` by value.

Comment: @Yuushi The reason why I'm doing this is because I didn't know better :D I'll add the `final` keyword to the class to seal it and I'll read up on virtual destructors. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### General remarks:

- Since you’re using C++11, use uniform initialisation syntax to initialise variables and class members.
- The `throw()` specification is deprecated and replaced by `noexcept`.
- The bracing style is somewhat inconsistent (new line or same line?).
- Inheriting from `std::exception` obviates need for `what`, `m_message`:

  ```
  class LevelLoadException : public std::exception {
  public:
      LevelLoadException(std::string msg) : std::exception{msg} {}
  };
  ```

  (Note the use of uniform initialisation syntax.)
- Getters and especially setters are [generally considered harmful](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf) in C++. This is not a rigid rule, but in your case there are better options:

  - Refactor `{Get,Set}TileAt` into an `operator()(int, int)`, and maybe put it into an own class rather than `Level` (single responsibility …). Also consider whether the setter is needed at all. In any case, usage should look like this:

    ```
    Level lvl;
    // …
    Tile a = lvl(1, 2);
    lvl(1, 2) = Tile::Free;
    ```

    or

    ```
    Tile b = lvl.tiles(1, 2);
    lvl.tiles(1, 2) = Tile::Free;
    ```
  - `GetPlayerStart{X,Y}` should be *one* function and return a `Point` (or, at the minimum, a `std::tuple<int, int>`). And there’s no need for the `Get` prefix; the same goes for `GetName`. `PlayerStart` and `Name` are sufficient and idiomatic (compare `std::vector::length`, `std::stringstream::str` etc.).
- `LoadFromFile` should return its result by value, not pointer.
- Consider using `constexpr` for the `static const int`s.
- Consider only offering a single means of construction:

  - *Either* via overloaded constructors
  - *or* via static creator functions (`LoadFromFile`, `Load`)

  Constructor would be more canonical C++ but in this case static functions are arguably more readable. Either way, mixing construction via functions and constructors makes the interface inconsistent.
- I would probably rewrite `LoadFromFile` slightly, incorporating several changes. Since the code is long-ish, [I’ve uploaded it as a gist](https://gist.github.com/klmr/0816a6e64a6e8cc846b7). the salient changes are:

  - Use range-based `for` loop, treat `x` and `y` iterating analogously to each other.
  - Use prefix increment instead of postfix. It doesn’t make a difference for `int` but it *can* make a difference in general, and using prefix increment is never less efficient (and sometimes more).
  - Separate parsing of level name and tiles
  - Remove code duplication (assigning tile)

#### Answering your specific question:

- Modulo what I’ve said above, the exception(-usage) looks good.
- The `enum class` is fine, there’s no portability problem. I’m somewhat surprised that you can use the constants as `switch` labels for a `char` (there’s normally no implicit conversion between an `enum class` and its underlying type).
- For arguments passed by value, adding `const` to the argument type in the prototype *does nothing* and serves no purpose. For the *implementation*, there’s a difference (and I argue that *all* arguments should be passed as `const`, but I’m inconsistent in enforcing this in my own code): a `const` argument cannot be modified inside the function, which is usually desired. But at any rate, a modification would only be visible inside the class because the argument is a copy of the value passed in by the user.
- The constructor looks OK-ish but rvalue references prevent calling the constructor with variable:

  ```
  std::vector<Tile> tiles{…};
  std::string mapname{"Test"};
  Level lvl{tiles, mapname, 0, 0};
  ```

  This doesn’t compile – you’d need to `move` the values and this is cumbersome and might not be desired anyway.

  There’s a simple solution: just accept the argument by value. That way, they’ll be copied when necessary (in the above case), and moved where possible (rvalue reference, such as from a temporary object). However, you now have to `move` them explicitly into their members:

  ```
  Level::Level(std::vector<Tile> tiles, std::string mapName, int playerStartX, int playerStartY)
      : m_tiles{std::move(tiles)}
      , m_name{std::move(mapName)}
      , m_playerStartX{playerStartX}
      , m_playerStartY{playerStartY} {}
  ```

(And again, consider using a `Point` object for the player start position.)

Comment: I strongly agree with the suggestions to use `std::exception`'s message handling and to avoid explicitly specifying rvalue references for `Level`'s constructor.

Comment: Why should `LoadFromFile` return a Level by value (Doesn't that mean the caller has to wrap it in a `unique_ptr`)? Basically the intent is to create a `Level` somewhere in memory and then tell the caller "There you go, you're now the sole owner of the object and responsible for deleting it when done"? Are there any guidelines when to return a value and when a pointer? (Doesn't return by value make a copy of the object it just built? Not a big deal here, just trying to understand the concepts and rules)

Comment: @Michael Because in C++ the rule is essentially: unless you absolutely **need** a pointer, use a value. In your case, there’s no need for a pointer (the object isn’t polymorphic, and storage is not an issue). Don’t wrap it into a `unique_ptr` outside either (that wouldn’t work directly anyway) – just use the value.

Answer (score 3):

**A few unnecessary includes:**

`Level.h` doesn't need to include `<iostream>`. That's the header file 
where `cout`, `cin` and other logs are defined. You are not using any of those.

`Level.cpp` includes `<sstream>`. Again, I don't see any type declared on that
file in use here. Probably a left-over from the previous code?

**LevelLoadException:**

You can move the string in the constructor to avoid a copy:

```
LevelLoadException(std::string msg) 
    : m_message{ std::move(msg) } 
{ 
}
```

Note that I've used the new uniform initialization syntax here (the `m_message{ }`). Personally, I like the old constructor style just as well. So the choice is up to you. Pick one that suits you best.

**Const parameters even when passing by value?**

The benefit you gain by making parameters passed by copy/value `const` is
in code correctness. This will prevent accidental modification of
parameters inside the function, so in my opinion, yes, I approve
the use of `const` even on copies.

**Public constructor plus factory function?**

Having the factory method `LoadFromFile()` and a public constructor
doesn't make much sense, as anyone can bypass the factory. Didn't you
mean to place the `Level` constructor in the *private* section?

However, if the goal here is to allow instantiation only via the factory method
you still have to disable the default copy constructor and possibly the assignment operator.

As its stands, users of `Level` can:

```
std::unique_ptr<Level> lvl = LoadFromFile(...); // ok

Level foo(*lvl); // also ok
```

To disallow the possibly undesired operations, you can `delete` the 
default constructor and `=` operator the compiler would implicitly add:

```
Level(const Level &) = delete;
Level & operator = (const Level &) = delete;
// Now the only way to create a Level is thru the factory, 
// assuming you've made the other constructor with params private too.
```

Refer to [**the rule of three/five/zero**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for more.

**Why vector anyway?**

So, it turn out that the size of the `tiles/m_tiles` vector is the constant `TileCount`.
So why bother using `std::vector`, which is a dynamically allocated, resizeable array,
if the array will never change size? Consider using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead. Array is a fixed size container that does not allocate memory, therefore, can be a good optimization if many levels are created.

**Miscellaneous:**

The implementation of  the `LoadFromFile()` method is fairly long. Consider breaking it into more specific helper methods.

---

```
int lineLength = line.length();
```

The actual return type of `std::string::length()` is an `std::string::size_type`, which in turn is
a typedef to `size_t`. I won't ask you to use the absurdly long `std::string::size_type`, but `size_t` is much 
better and safer than `int`.

When you replace it, then make the loop counter of this `for()` also a `size_t` to avoid a signed/unsigned comparison warning:

```
for (int x=0; x < lineLength; x++)
```

To:

```
for (size_t x = 0; x < lineLength; ++x)
```

---

Please align these constants properly, it is much more readable:

```
enum class Tile : char { 
    Unknown     = 0,
    Free        = ' ',
    Box         = '+',
    Target      = '.',
    Wall        = '=',
    BoxOnTarget = '*',
    PlayerStart = 'x'
};
```

Comment: `Level` doesn’t have a default constructor, no need to delete it. Default constructors are only generated when no other constructor is supplied by the user. Using `std::array` here would bloat the size of the `Level` object and might burst the stack – I advise against this: automatic objects should almost without exceptions be small, no more than, say, a few dozen bytes.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, you are absolutely right about the constructor, my mistake. `Tile` is the size of a char and `TileCount` is `600`. Using a static array would add `600` bytes to the class. This will depend on the application, but usually, that is not a huge size; `Level` objects are already allocated dynamically by the factory method, so I do think it is nonsense to have a double allocation in this case.

Comment: And BTW, having the tile array directly inside `Level` would have the added benefit of better data locality / CPU cache efficiency.

Comment: The locality is lost once you return a pointer to the level object rather than the value. Which should of course nor be done: treat levels as values, and allocate the larger memory (tiles) on the heap.

Comment: I can agree with that!